# Which exchange of money is best?

Tags: dominion, statistics

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Should I trash copper or silver with Mine?](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/3397/should-i-trash-copper-or-silver-with-mine)

In dominion you have the option when the Mine cards are in use to trash a treasure and put a treasure worth 3 more in your hand. In effect you can remove a copper form the game and gain a silver, remove a silver and gain a gold etc.

**Is there a *statistical* benefit to rushing towards gold/platinum?**

Is it best to get all of your copper pieces into silver *then* into gold. Or should you focus getting to the highest possible denomination, and keep coppers in your deck (until you have nothing else to *Mine* besides copper)?

Something tells me one is better than the other due to the number of cards one strategy leaves you with, as opposed to the other.

Comment: The other thread doesn't really cover anything statistical. Just strategy's when using other cards.

Comment: I was a latecomer, but I tried to be statistical in [my answer](http://boardgames.stackexchange.com/a/4717/1749)

Comment: Well, it is almost all the way at the bottom. Too bad since I think it's one of my best answers.