# When playing the Mine, which Treasure do you upgrade first?

Tags: dominion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Should I trash copper or silver with Mine?](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/3397/should-i-trash-copper-or-silver-with-mine)

In Dominion, when playing the Mine card, you can "*Trash a Treasure card from your hand. Gain a Treasure card costing up to 3 Coins more; put it into your hand.*". If you have only Copper or Silver in your hand, then the choice is obvious which to upgrade. If you have both Copper and Silver in your hand, what are the pros and cons to upgrading one over the other?

Comment: Welcome to the site!  This question has been asked already and I've linked you to it.  If there is some aspect not covered by the earlier question, feel free to clarify here, or ask in another question.  Thanks!

Comment: I definitely agree. It's a duplicate. Thanks for pointing me to the previous question. There is a lot of good discussion there.